# Android. Searching over the listView

Tags: android, search, listview

I have activity with ListView. That listView contains imageView and two textViews (aka first and last names). I want to organize searching with this listView by one of textView (e.g. by last name). 
How can I implement that?

I found that Quick Search Box can be used but I didn't understand how to work with it.

Help, plz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTextFilterEnabled(boolean)`  method.

If it does not solve your problem then you can also define your own filter.

For this please see this post [android-how-do-i-overwrite-the-filter-for-my-arrayadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208225/android-how-do-i-overwrite-the-filter-for-my-arrayadapter/2606896#2606896)

Hope this helps !!

Comment: yes, I can do filtering this way, but currently I don't know about gui implementatio of typing the search keyword. I know that android has Quick Search box, which has its own dialog for typing search keyword. It would be better to use it instead of using filtering (or maybe find a way to link QSB and List filtering). Do you have any suggestions about this?

Comment: I mean This way very useful for devices with hardware keyboards .. but QSB is effective for devices without hardware keyboards ... so I think it would be better to implement QSB, but I found no way how can I do that

Comment: I found a way to show software keyboard, using which I can use filtering:

InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);